# Minimum of squared sum minus sum of squares

Tags: inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I know that
$$
\min_{\|x\|_2=1=\|y\|_2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k\right)^2-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2y_k^2 \geq -1/2
$$
with equality whenever $|x_k|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=|y_k|$ for two coordinates.

I'm wondering if there's a sharper version that one can prove wherein $x$ is *fixed* and we only minimize over $y$, i.e.,
$$
\min_{\|y\|_2=1} \left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k\right)^2-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2y_k^2 \geq\ ??
$$

Presumably the lower bound should depend on the sparsity of $x$, and something like its `variance'
$$
\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(x_k-\mu(x))^2.
$$

For example, in the initial problem, if $n$ is even and we take $|x_k|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ with an alternating sign, then the minimum grows to $-1/n$.  Here $\mu(x)=0$ and $\sigma(x)=1/n^2$.  The minimum is achieved for $y$ with the same mean and variance.  On the contrary, if $x_1=1$ (so $x$ has maximal variance) we find the minimum is 0 and is achieved for *any* $y$.

**Are there any inequalities that reduce to these extreme cases but shed light on the intermediate ones as well?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate some on the last two sentences of Robert's answer, here's what I would view as the standard procedure to analyze the rank one perturbation $D^2-xx^t$. I'll proceed as in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193527/about-adding-a-negative-definite-rank-1-matrix-to-a-symmetric-matrix/193592#193592) of mine. It's convenient to have $x$ as a cyclic vector for $D^2$; this will be the case in the generic situation where all $x_j^2$ are distinct and non-zero, and I can then obtain the other cases by approximation. Let's in fact assume that $0<x_1^2<\ldots < x_n^2$.

As spelt out in that answer, the eigenvalues of $A=D^2-xx^t$ are then the points $\lambda$ with $F(\lambda)=1$, where $F(z)=x^t(D^2-z)^{-1}x$ is the matrix element of the resolvent. Since $D$ is diagonal, this is easily evaluated and we obtain
$$
F(\lambda) = \sum \frac{x_j^2}{x_j^2-\lambda} = 1
$$
as the condition determining the eigenvalues. There is one such $\lambda$ in each interval $(-\infty, x_1^2)$, $(x_1^2,x_2^2), \ldots, (x_{n-1}^2,x_n^2)$. As explained by Robert, here we are interested in the solution $\lambda\in (x_{n-1}^2,x_n^2)$, and your minimum equals $-\lambda$.

In the cases you mentioned, this gives $-\lambda = -1/n$ (for the simple reason that we must find $\lambda$ between $x_{n-1}^2=1/n$ and $x_n^2=1/n$) and $\lambda=0$, respectively. In general, we see that quantities such as $\mu(x)$ or $\sigma(x)$ are in fact not very relevant (certainly not if $x_{n-1}^2$ is close to $x_n^2$).

Comment: I should also point out that the inequality $x_{n-1}^2\le\lambda\le x_n^2$ is just the interlacing property, I don't need to look at resolvents for this.

Comment: Very nice!  Follow-up question: suppose we're looking at $D^2+\alpha xx^T$ for some $\alpha>0$.  Then your analysis yields the *largest* eigenvalue is *lower*-bounded by $\alpha x_n^2$.  It seems that it *might* be possible to analyze $F(\lambda)$ further and deduce a more interesting upper-bound than $\sum x_k^2$?

Comment: @squattyroo: This (a rank-one perturbation with a coupling constant) is actually the situation I'm most familiar with. Somewhat unexpectedly, it's a pretty interesting subject; Barry Simon has a very readable review article on this, if you want to know more.

Comment: @squattyroo: To address your actual comment, if $A=D^2+\alpha xx^t$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, then the calculation from the other answer now gives $G_{\alpha}=F/(1+\alpha F)$, and thus the eigenvalues of $A$ are now the solutions of $F(\lambda)=-1/\alpha$ (above we're in the special case $\alpha=-1$). The (interlacing) bounds stay the same though (if $\alpha>0$, there's no eigenvalue below the spectrum of $D^2$ and instead there's one above the spectrum).

Answer (score 6):

If $z_k = x_k y_k$, the quantity you're looking at is
$$ y^T D Q D y = \left(\sum_k z_k\right)^2 - \sum_k z_k^2$$

where $Q$ is the $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with diagonal terms $0$ and off-diagonal terms $1$, and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $x_k$.  What you're asking for is the least eigenvalue of $DQD$.  Now $Q = -I + e e^T$ where $e$ is the vector of all $1$'s, so $$DQD = -D^2 + (De)(e^TD) = -D^2 + x x^T$$ is a rank-one perturbation of $-D^2$.
This sort of thing has been studied quite a bit, I think.  See for example
[this recent paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965912001073). (*Cheng, Guanghui; Luo, Xiaoxue; Li, Liang*, [**The bounds of the smallest and largest eigenvalues for rank-one modification of the Hermitian eigenvalue problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2012.02.036), Appl. Math. Lett. 25, No. 9, 1191-1196 (2012). [ZBL1255.15025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1255.15025). [MR2930744](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2930744).)