# Minimising the squared sum minus the sum of squares

Tags: inequalities, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

I'd like to know how to show $$\min_{\Vert x\Vert_2=1=\Vert y\Vert_2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_ky_k\right)^2-\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2y_k^2\geq -1/2.$$

The inequality is discussed in a previous post [Minimum of squared sum minus sum of squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/206615/minimum-of-squared-sum-minus-sum-of-squares) but it's not clear to me how to prove this.

Comment: What norm do you use? Where's this from?

Comment: @BeniBogosel The euclidean norm...it's from a previous post ''minimum of squared sum minus sum of squares'' but the inequality was assumed without proof

Comment: Providing a link to that post and clarifying the question would make people more inclined to answer your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've added the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should oftentimes be the case that, analyzing a "thoughtless" Lagrange multiplier solution, one finds a more elegant, "clever" solution. At least, this is the case here. Analyzing the previous Lagrange multiplier solution, one can obtain the following.

We need to show that
$$\sum x_j^2 y_j^2\le1/2+\Big(\sum x_j y_j\Big)^2\tag{0}$$
given that $\sum x_j^2=1$ and $\sum y_j^2=1$.

Let
$$s_+:=\sum_{j\colon\,x_jy_j>0}x_jy_j,\quad s_-:=-\sum_{j\colon\,x_jy_j<0}x_jy_j.$$
Then $s_+-s_-=\sum x_jy_j$ and $s_++s_-=\sum|x_jy_j|\le\sqrt{\sum x_j^2}\sqrt{\sum y_j^2}=1$, by the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality. Also, $\sum x_j^2 y_j^2\le s_+^2+s_-^2$.
So, (0) reduces to $s_+^2+s_-^2\le1/2+(s_+-s_-)^2$, which simplifies to $s_+ s_-\le1/4$, which latter holds because $s_\pm\ge0$ and $s_++s_-\le1$. So, (0) is proved.

Comment: Nice improvement. I've uploaded the complex version here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373609/generalisation-of-the-squared-sum-minus-the-sum-of-squares-inequality

Answer (score 5):

We need to show that
$$\sum x_j^2 y_j^2\le1/2+\Big(\sum x_j y_j\Big)^2\tag{0}\label{0}$$
given that $\sum x_j^2=1$ and $\sum y_j^2=1$.

Consider the maximization of $\sum x_j^2 y_j^2$ for a fixed value of $\sum x_j y_j$ assuming also $\sum x_j^2=1$ and $\sum y_j^2=1$. Then (see e.g. the [Carathéodory Multiplier Rule, page 441](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320250?seq=1))
$$Ax_j y_j^2=ax_j+cy_j,\tag{1}\label{1}$$
$$Ax_j^2 y_j=by_j+cx_j\tag{2}\label{2}$$
for any maximizer $((x_j),(y_j))$, some real Lagrange multipliers $A\in\{0,1\},a,b,c$ (not all of which equal $0$), and all $j$.

Multiplying \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} by $x_j$ and $y_j$, respectively, and then subtracting, we get $ax_j^2=by_j^2$ for all $j$. Summing in $j$, we get $a=b$.

*Case 1: $a=b\ne0$.* Then for each $j$ we have $x_j^2=y_j^2=:u_j\ge0$ and hence $y_j=\pm x_j$. Then \eqref{0} becomes
$$\sum u_j^2\le1/2+(s_+-s_-)^2,\tag{0'}\label{0'}$$
where $$s_\pm:=\sum_{j\colon\, y_j=\pm x_j}u_j.$$
Note that $\sum u_j^2\le s_+^2+s_-^2$. So, \eqref{0'} reduces to $s_+s_-\le1/4$, which holds because $s_+ + s_-=\sum u_j=\sum x_j^2=1$. So, \eqref{0} holds in Case 1.

*Case 2: $a=b=0$ and $A=1$.* Then, by \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}, for each $j$ we have $x_jy_j=0$ or $x_jy_j=c$. So, \eqref{0} becomes
$$kc^2\le1/2+(kc)^2,\tag{0''}\label{0''}$$
where $k$ is the cardinality of the set $\{j\colon x_jy_j=c\}$. Since $k=0$ or $k\ge1$, \eqref{0''} holds and hence \eqref{0} holds in Case 2.

*Case 3: $a=b=0$ and $A=0$.* Then $c\ne0$ and hence, by \eqref{1}, $y_j=0$ for all $j$, which contradicts the condition $\sum y_j^2=1$. So, Case 3 cannot occur.

Thus, \eqref{0} holds in all the cases.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you. I was also wondering what happens if you assume x and y are complex unit vectors, so the sum in brackets on the RHS of (0) is the inner product of x and y. I think the inequality still holds but can this proof be generalised?

Comment: @Luke : Then $x_j^2$, $y_j^2$, and the square of the inner product of $x$ and $y$ will in general be complex, and thus the inequality will lose meaning. You may want to ask instead what happens if you replace $x_j^2$, $y_j^2$, and the square of the inner product of $x$ and $y$ by the squares of the corresponding moduli. I think then you could use Lagrange multipliers too, but the whole thing would become more, maybe much more  complicated. Since your question has been fully answered, I suggest you post the complex version of it separately, if you want to pursue this matter further.