# Is there some quantitative version of interlacing of eigenvalues of a matrix under rank-1 update?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, graph-theory, convex-optimization, spectral-graph-theory

Given a real symmetric matrix $A$ and a vector $v$ of the same dimension we know that the eigenvalues of $A + vv^T$ are left interlaced by the eigenvalues of $A$.

- But do we have any quantitative estimates of the amount of interlacing produced?

  Like as a function of $A$ and $v$ if we can say how much will the $k^{th}$ eigenvalue of $A+vv^T$ be ahead of the $k^{th}$ eigenvalue of $A$? (at least under some restrictions about the nature of $A$ and $v$?)

Comment: This seems to be the same question that you asked earlier here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193527/about-adding-a-negative-definite-rank-1-matrix-to-a-symmetric-matrix/193592#193592

Comment: @ChristianRemling They are not the same though its about the same concept. Here I am asking if we know of any bounds on the shifts that would happen.

Comment: If you look at the trace you will see the total change of the eigenvalues. How this change distributes between the eigenvalues depends on where $v$ is with respect to the eigenvectors.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay True. But is that a way to quantify the shift in the eigenvalues in terms of A and v?

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to perform calculations in another direction: Instead of starting with $A$ and $v$, start with the spectrum of $A$ and the intended spectrum of $A+vv^\top$. One may use these spectra to calculate how much of $v$'s energy must lie in each eigenspace of $A$ (see for example Theorem 4 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.0921)). Since your question concerns the "inverse" formula, I suspect the bounds you seek will quickly follow.

Comment: Is your linked paper making rank-1 updates? Can you may be help translate between the two terminologies?

Comment: @Anirbit: $F_{n+1}F_{n+1}^*=F_nF_n+f_{n+1}f_{n+1}^*$

Comment: So $A = F_nF_n$ and $v = f_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: @Anirbit: Indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You might have noticed that I had asked a related question here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/208019/can-one-estimate-the-distribution-of-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-by-its-cauchy-stiel/208101?noredirect=1#comment515849_208101