# How are eigenvalues and eigenvectors affected by adding the all-ones matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and the $n\times n$ all-ones matrix $J = (1)_{ij}$, I'm interested in the relation between the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrices $A$ and $A+J$, or more generally $A_t := A + tJ$.

Is there a nice description of the eigenvalues or eigenvectors of $A_t$ in terms of those of $A$? If not, what about for $t$ small?

It would be great to have an answer for general coefficient fields, but I would also be interested in the case with $A \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ or $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with all nonnegative or positive entries, if they have nicer answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193527/about-adding-a-negative-definite-rank-1-matrix-to-a-symmetric-matrix/193592#193592

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a special case of a *rank one perturbation* or a *rank one update*, and there is plenty of work on such. See the [nice 2010 lecture notes by Andre Ran.](http://www.cs.vu.nl/~ran/LectureBerlijn2010.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! The phrase "rank one update" was very useful to know. Among other things it lead me to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Answer (score 12):

A cute fact that is trivial to prove is this: define the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $M$ by $\phi_M(x) = |xI-M|$. Then for any $A$ and any $s$, $$\phi_{A+sJ}(x) = (1-s)\phi_A(x)+s\phi_{A+J}(x).$$
The proof only needs the fact that a determinant doesn't change when a multiple of one row is added to a different row, so I don't see why it wouldn't be true for all fields.

Comment: In other words, $\det(A+sJ)=\det(A)+s\mathrm{Tr}(J\cdot \wedge^{n-1}A)$ is an affine function of $s$.

Comment: @abx could you write in matrix form what $J.\wedge^{n-1}A$ is?