# Is adding an outer product to a matrix guaranteed to not decrease the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ and a vector $v$, will adding $v v^T$ to $A$ always increase or keep the eigenvalues of $A$ the same? The sum of the eigenvectors of $A + v v^T$ should be greater or equal to the sum of the eigenvectors of $A$ due to $tr(A + v v^T) = tr(A) + tr(v v^T)$, but one could increase one of the eigenvalues of the result matrix while decreasing another and still satisfy the sum increasing.

Comment: Are you assuming that $A$ is symmetric?  In that case it should be true because $vv^T$ is positive semidefinite, but in general the eigenvalues need not even be real numbers.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification, I have edited the question. A is assumed symmetric.

Comment: In that case, it was already answered (for the version where you subtract $vv^T$ and reduce the eigenvalues) in an earlier MO question, with the additional information that each eigenvalue increases to at most the next-largest one, attributed to Cauchy: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193527/about-adding-a-negative-definite-rank-1-matrix-to-a-symmetric-matrix

Comment: Each eigenvalue increases; this is immediate from the min-max principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem. Questions of this type are not really suited for this site. Please ask at MSE instead.